# how to extract a number from a String using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract `12345 Rial` from the String `s` :

```
String regx= ".* (\\d*) Rial";
String  s = "your balance is 12345 Rial your last"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

but the following exception is being thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at ir.dena.avl.server.util.modbus.ChargeMessage.getBalanceFromIranCell(ChargeMessage.java:95)
```

Can anyone point out why?

Comment: Do you want to extract both the number and the adjacent word in the same regex?

Comment: no i only want to extract number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern first needs to be found before you will be able to use it. You need to use either `find` or `matches` first methods from Matcher class to traverse string and get match.

So use

```
...
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

or if you want to make sure that entire string is matched by regex

```
...
if (matcher.matches())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```